# Gradual raise in activity since Early August till the Present date at Great outdoors

Tags: discussion

I have been on this site for mere 3 months now. Over the time I have observed a gradual raise in activity here at Great Outdoors. Feels very happy it being this way. Just curious to know how have we managed this.

Comment: It might have to do with the summer coming to a close and people sitting in front of their computers again... Let's hope it is not just that!

Comment: @DudeOnRock -- In my case yes. I post less in summer because I'm too busy hiking!

Comment: @RussellSteen: Same here!

Comment: Strange you should say this, because my general feeling (haven't looked at any real data) is the opposite. In the last few months this site has become less interesting. Perhaps it's because we are getting a lot more questions on technical climbing, which I don't do, so I tune them out. What's left seems slim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been on here for about 600 days, and without seeing the mod info, it feels like this increase is partly due to an end of season increase, but feels much bigger than last year's - which has to be down to the overall growth. As we get bigger, we get bigger.

The breadth of questions is getting much wider as well, which helps us reach a wider audience. For the first few months we seemed very narrow in scope, but now we have questions in a wide range of areas I know nothing about - which is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

There might be seasonal variation, but I think the most reasonable explination is mostly duration. The longer this community/site exists, the larger out content grows the easier it will be found by new people. A good identification of this can be a rising view count on old questions.

While we have some direct exposure from say travel.stackexchange.com, we could all aid by promoting this website to our friends or on social media.